# images/icons only appearing after I hover over them

Tags: html, image

For some weird reason, images and icons only appear after I hover over them.

For example, this appears firstly:

### [image: blank images]

After I hover over it with my mouse:

### [image: non-blank images]

Is this a memory issue?

Here is the website link for reference: www.drimmit.com/inspiration.

Thanks!

Comment: No issue here in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'm using chrome on Mac... I'm wondering if that would be the problem?